# Default apply parent styles to inner child DOM element

Tags: asp.net, css, html, dom

How do i make my inner span inside the paragraph inherit the styles defined in the paragraph ?

```
<p class='NavnAdr2 Normal' style='line-height: 12pt; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;
                        font-family: Times New Roman;'>
                        <span>Sample test</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set inherit for each Css-attribute.

```
<span style="line-height: inherit; margin-top: inherit; margin-bottom: inherit;  font-family: inherit;">Sample test</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing inline styles try applying styles to the `p` tag & all `span` tags under it as:

```
.NavnAdr2, .NavnAdr2 span {
  line-height: 12pt; 
  margin-top: 0pt; 
  margin-bottom: 0pt;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```